# Getting unexpected response code 403 and com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-volley, http-status-code-403

I was developing an android application with Kotlin which uses the newsapi and fetches data from it namely title, author, url, urlToImage, and displays it in a RecyclerView.

Given below is the code for the Main Activity which does the API job:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor.UncaughtThrowableStrategy.LOG
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.logging.Logger

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NewsItemClicked {
    override fun onItemClick(item: News) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    private lateinit var mAdapter:NewsRecyclerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var recyclerView : RecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerview)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        Toast.makeText(this,"starting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        fetchData()
        mAdapter = NewsRecyclerAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }

    private fun fetchData(){
        val url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=09b4495143d14205bf044ca1784d6f3e"
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            Response.Listener {
                val newsArray=ArrayList<News>()
                val newsJsonArray = it.getJSONArray("articles")
                for(i in 0 until newsJsonArray.length()){
                    val obj=newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    val news = News(
                        obj.getString("title") ,
                        obj.getString("author"),
                        obj.getString("url"),
                        obj.getString("urlToImage")
                    )
                    newsArray.add(news)
                }
                mAdapter.updateNews(newsArray)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                error->Log.e("String",error.toString())
                Toast.makeText(this,"Oops! There's some issue collecting the news feed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        )
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
    }

}
```

When I run the app in my emulator, it is unable to display the news in the recycler View and the following error is shown in the logcat:

```
2020-10-27 18:18:00.989 13763-13801/com.example.thenewsapp E/Volley: [758] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=09b4495143d14205bf044ca1784d6f3e
2020-10-27 18:18:01.286 13763-13801/com.example.thenewsapp E/Volley: [758] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=09b4495143d14205bf044ca1784d6f3e
2020-10-27 18:18:01.288 13763-13763/com.example.thenewsapp E/String: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
```

I tried to comment out all the recycler view Code from the main activity to check whether the issue is raised by the recycler view or not. But once again, the same error was showing up in the logcat which means that the error was in the API part.

The API key provided is a valid one. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app in the emulator but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

add user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 in header of the request

Answer (score 0):

You have to add headers in the request, It started working for me once I added the headers in the request as below.

```
{
    /**
     * Passing some request headers
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("content-type", "application/json");
        headers.put("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
        headers.put("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");

        return headers;
    }
}
```